# Laravel get data from external post submit: TokenMismatchException ( without adding _token)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a form that only have control on action URL. so cannot add '_token'. is that possible to get the data to my controller

External HTML form host in deference location

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="http://www.mylaravelproject.com/confirm">
    <input type="textbox" name="fname">
    <input type="textbox" name="lname">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My Laravel Route

```
Route::any('confirm','PageController@confirm');
```

Inside Controller

```
public function confirm(){
return Input::all();
}
```

Is this Possible ??

Thanks

**Edit:**

Found i can do that by removing line (inside App/Httm/Kenel.php)

```
'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
```

**Second Question**
but its kind of security risk. i Just only need to remove VerifyCsrfToken on this specific route 'confirm'.

is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature will be available in Laravel 5.1 out of the box.

But while we wait for Laravel 5.1 - you can do this in your `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` file in 5.0:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;
use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier {

    protected $excludedRouteGroups = ['confirm', 'stripe'];


    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->isReading($request) || ($this->excludedRoutes($request)) || $this->tokensMatch($request)) {
            return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
        }

        Throw new TokenMismatchException;
    }


    protected function excludedRoutes($request)
    {
        foreach($this->excludedRouteGroups as $route) {
            if ($request->segment(1) === $route) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```